# Reality to Fiction: Powerfully Built Humans?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, character-creation, creature-size, racial-traits

[Hafþór Björnsson](https://www.facebook.com/pages/Haf%C3%BE%C3%B3r-J%C3%BAl%C3%ADus-Bj%C3%B6rnsson-Hafthor-Julius-Bjornsson/132803286824288) is 6' 9" (2.05 m) and 419 lbs. (190.005 kg). That is a pretty good reason he was cast as [The Mountain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_A_Song_of_Ice_and_Fire_characters#Gregor_Clegane) on [Game of Thrones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_of_Thrones) - not to mention he is a very popular [Strongman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World%27s_Strongest_Man).

When we look at the [Height and Weight Table](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/description.htm#heightAndWeight) we see the maximum for a human male would be 6' 6" and 280 lb. Hafthor is taller and bigger than that. In fact, in the TV Show, he is often seen swinging a [zweihander](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zweih%C3%A4nder) with one hand.

[image: The Mountain]

- Would he be a large creature?
- Would he instead have Powerful Build?

If I wanted to create The Mountain, how could I do this? I think he would be an excellent archetype. Should I just use [Jotunbrud](http://www.realmshelps.net/charbuild/feat/Jotunbrud) and [Monkey Grip](https://haven-hinterlands.obsidianportal.com/wikis/monkey-grip)? Is there a feat, even if it is 3<sup>rd</sup> Party that would give at least the benefit of Powerful Build without the drawback of Monkey Grip?

Comment: A bit off topic, but I'm pretty sure that's not a zwiehander. They tend to have a secondary cross guard a little ways down the blade and a duller section of blade between the two cross guards.

Comment: @EpsilonRose There were [zweihanders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zweih%C3%A4nder#/media/File:Zweihaender_im_historischen_Museum_Basel.JPG) that did not have the Parierhaken (parrying guards).

Comment: Really you are both right. It appears to be a scaled up version of an English Longsword, but that would make it a Zweihaender. Sure, it does not have the look of a Zweihaender, but it is the length that is really what makes a sword a Zweihaender.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No**, and **Maybe**.
Medium sized creatures range all the way up to 8ft and 500lbs. So he is still well within that range. He is bigger and stronger by quite a bit than a normal human, but is still nothing special compared to other medium sized creatures.

Additionally, all creatures with **powerful build** I am aware of ([Half-Giant](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/monsters/halfGiant.htm)) are a bit larger than The Mountain. Still, in universe The Mountain probably is half (or some fraction) giant, and while he is quite a bit shorter than the 3.5e Half-Giant he is very stocky. So **powerful build** is not completely unreasonable.

If you were looking for a way to bring him into a 3.5e setting, Half-Giant would likely be the closest starting point.

Comment: @AOKost *Don't* ask new questions in comments.

Comment: I checked the Goliath stats: 7' to 8' and 280 lb. to 340 lb., so a bit tighter spectrum than Half-Giant and actually lighter than The Mountain.